# Attaching the foldername to all the all files in that particular folder

Tags: scripting, batch-file

There are 100s of folders in a directory and inside each of the folder there is a `(filename).ini` file.

All I need to do is to attach the parent folder name to the .ini file so that it becomes `(foldername)-(filename).txt` file.

Is there a batch script which could do this? i am new to batch files. So, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you use Windows you can start from [this](http://superuser.com/questions/205083/command-line-recursive-rename-move-in-windows) blog entry, for linux see [this other one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=679657).

Comment: For which operating system do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /R %%a in (*.ini) do (
  set relativepath=%%a
  set relativepath=!relativepath:%cd%\=!
  set newname=!relativepath:\=-!
  set newname=!newname:.ini=.txt!
  ren !relativepath! !newname!
)

endlocal
```

Comment: +1, But it fails if you start from a root directory, as `CD` resolves to `C:\` with an appended slash

Answer (score 0):

This works for any folder and any folder structure.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%a in (*.ini) do (
  set foldername=%%~pa
  set foldername=!foldername:\=_!
  echo ren "%%~fa" "(!foldername!)-%%~na.txt"
)
```

For all the ini files in the current directory: extract the path from the filename, using the `~p` modifier; change all backslash occurrencies to underscores, using the `:=` modifier; finally rename the original ini file.

After testing, remove the `ECHO`

See `HELP FOR` and `HELP SET` for more information.